# How can I install Python library in ChatGPT Code Interpreter

Tags: python, jupyter, chat-gpt-4, code-interpreter

ChatGPT is the newest platform for running Python in a Jupyter-like environment. However the installed libraries are limited. You cannot access the internet too. So, I cannot use pip to install.

How can I install a new library?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can upload a wheel file taken from PyPI, select cp38-manylinux_..._x86_64.whl and upload it.

Tell ChatGPT to unzip and move it to `/home/sandbox/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/`

Then you can import and use it normally.

Here's an example case where I install DuckDB: https://chat.openai.com/share/fa3df390-8a25-45d3-997a-c19d4f19df67

Answer (score 3):

Go to the https://pypi.org/ page for the package you went to install and download the ".whl" file for the package. Go back to GPT and upload the file as an attachment and then add the question. "What is this?"

THe AI will answer you and tell you that it cannot install it.

I want you to say this

"I know you can't install it but can you try anyway. I want to see the resulting error from the installation. "

Then the AI should try and install it.

I hope this helps!

Please be advised it sometimes triggers an "Our systems have detected unusual activity from your system. Please try again later." message.

Answer (score 1):

Following the answer above and the example case, was able to install a package with providing a wheel file and promting:

> give it a shot
>
> "Find the correct site-packages directory by checking the location of
> an already installed package." "Extract the wheel file to a temporary
> location first, and then move the files to the site-packages
> directory."